# Find instance of string in git core with 'git grep'

Tags: git, github

I found a minor issue in `git` (bad Spanish translation) and reported it vita the [git mailing list](http://git@vger.kernel.org).

I was told by a developer that it would be great if I could: clone the [git repo](https://github.com/git/git), find the files that contain the bad translation using `git grep`, patch it, and make a commit.

The thing is that using `git grep` I find no files where the bad translation could be.

Precisely, this is the bad translation:

```
Su rama está delante de <<origin/master<< para 6 commits.
```

and it should say:

```
Su rama está delante de <<origin/master<< por 6 commits.
```

(ie: `para`should be `por`).

To locate the sentence, I've tried:

```
git grep 'delante'
git grep 'delante' -- '*.[ch]'
```

as shown in the examples of [git-grep](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep) but both commands come back empty.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using `git version 1.9.1` BTW.

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, I will add it to the question.

Comment: The phrase probably isn't in a `.c` or `.h` file; it's likely in a [gettext `.po` file](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/PO-Files.html) or similar. Unfortunately, I can't find a Spanish translation file in the source tree, and I similarly can't find the phrase you're searching for.

Comment: Well, glad to know it's not just me then. I'll try emailing back and see what the git devs say about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the issue was that the sentence is not in `git` itself but rather in its Spanish Ubuntu translation: https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/+source/git/+pots/git/es/+filter?person=franciscomol

I've proposed the fixed translation over there.